# How to make gnuplot plugin *dll *so including functions

Tags: object, import, plugins, gnuplot

I recently read the gnuplot manual about `import` function.

The `import` command associates a user-defined function name with a function exported by an external shared object. This constitutes a plugin mechanism that extends the set of functions available in gnuplot.

Syntax:

```
import func(x[,y,z,...]) from "sharedobj[:symbol]"
```

Examples:

```
# make the function myfun, exported by "mylib.so" or "mylib.dll"
# available for plotting or numerical calculation in gnuplot
import myfun(x) from "mylib"
import myfun(x) from "mylib:myfun"    # same as above
```

So this means that I can read any functions from the developed dll or so files that anyone made.
If I have any functions to distribute anyone, how can I make this?
In the manual, no further information.

Comment: There is a README file and sample C code for a couple of simple plugins in the demo/plugin/ directory of the gnuplot distribution package. You should start there, and if you run into a problem then come back here with a more specific question showing your initial code and describing what did not work.

Comment: Sir, I cannot find the directory. No plugin directory. For more check, I have downloaded the latest one, no folder existing. Is there available on Linux version? Sorry for that, I found this on Linux version. Thanks,